# Make Error wth ceres

Tags: make

I'm getting this error:
error: ‘Eigen::UpLoType’ has not been declared
 template

I'm not sure what can be done here

Comment: Consider adding a bit more context, like the process by which you make the error occur.

Comment: I am having this same issue, I am following the instructions here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/db8/tutorial_sfm_installation.html, I am at the `make -j4` line